# Led bulb dims slightly and then brightens, repeatably, but very slow

Tags: lighting, led, light-bulb

I have googled a bunch on this, but everything talks about a fast flicker.  This is a real slow slight dimming, followed a second or to later by returning to full power.  And no descerable pattern, repeating slowly.

The fixture takes 3 bulbs, and they all seem to do it, though maybe they don't dim the same amount, it's hard to tell.

I tried replacing all 3 bulbs.  They are dimmable bulbs, but are on a regular switch.

I am thinking fixture, but how could it cause this?

Comment: Put 1 old incandescent bulb in 1 of the sockets. Do the remaining LEDs behave now?

Comment: That is a great idea.  Just need to find one though.

Comment: Finally got some incandescent bulbs and put them in.  They seem to work fine.  I also realized the same fixture was in another bathroom.  It had LED's in it too.  Though there were a different brand and higher wattage.

Comment: "them"?  I advised to install *1* incandescent bulb and leave the rest LEDs, *as a test* so we could narrow down the problem.  I did not suggest using incandescents forever, that would be a waste of money.